# Make gradle point to subdirectory and treat it as a rootProject

Tags: gradle

I encountered a problem with gradle project structure. I have a task that needs to be realized and some tests are meant to be executed to check whether my project structure is correct and the tasks in gradle execute correctly. However I think I misunderstood instruction a bit and I'm wondering whether I can do something with my current folders structure or If I will have to rewrite the whole project. My current project structure looks like this:

```
main-repo-folder/
├── docker-related-file
├── rootProject
│   ├── sub-project-1
│   ├── build(output from tasks is created here)
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── sub-project-2
│   ├── gradle
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
```

As you can see, the root project is a directory inside a repo. In order for my tests to execute I think the repo itself must be a root folder (or act as one) because the tests seem to be trying executing there. And here is my question, is it possible to add f.e settings.gradle file in main-repo-folder (at the same level as rootProject folder) to "point" gradle to build from rootProject and treat that folder as the root?(I mean f.e if I call `gradle clean build task_name` in main-repo-folder I want to make gradle execute it as I would be in rootProject folder)
I've tried to find some information but I'm at the path of learning gradle and I don't know if it is even possible :/ .

Answer (score 0):

Rename `main-repo-folder/rootProject` to `main-repo-folder`.